# How can I get my CustomView to have some imageViews in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I'm newbie to android and have a problem with it.

I'm trying to make a customized view in android for menu.

I want it to have 4 elements which have images.

But these are invisible though I coded like below :( What can I do for it ?

I've googled it for a while and there's no reasonable solution in my case ...

**Menuindicator.java**

```
public class MenuIndicator extends FrameLayout {

    private static final int MIN_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int MIN_HEIGHT = 50;

    private final float ACTUAL_PIXELS = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    private ImageView menuComponentAbove = null;
    private ImageView menuComponentBelow = null;
    private ImageView menuComponentFront = null;
    private ImageView menuComponentBack  = null;

    public MenuIndicator(Context context) {

        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }
    public MenuIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }
    public MenuIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        final TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MenuIndicator, defStyle, 0);

        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_menu_indicator, this);

        menuComponentAbove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_above);
        menuComponentBelow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_below);
        menuComponentFront = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_front);
        menuComponentBack  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_back);

        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = 0;

        switch(widthMode) {

            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:   widthSize = widthMeasureSpec; break;
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:       widthSize = (int)(MIN_WIDTH * ACTUAL_PIXELS); break;
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:       widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); break;
        }

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = 0;

        switch(heightMode) {

            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:   heightSize = heightMeasureSpec; break;
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:       heightSize = (int)(MIN_HEIGHT * ACTUAL_PIXELS); break;
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:       heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec); break;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        menuComponentAbove.draw(canvas);
        menuComponentBelow.draw(canvas);
        menuComponentFront.draw(canvas);
        menuComponentBack.draw(canvas);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**layout_menu_indicator.xml**

```
<!-- layout_menu_indicator.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:background="#171717">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_indicator"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_menu_indicator"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_menu_indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_component_front"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_component" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_component_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_component" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_component_above"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/menu_component_front"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_component" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_component_below"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/menu_component_front"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_component" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/command_container_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_menu_indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_indicator"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/command_container_vertical"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_menu_indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
public MenuIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_menu_indicator, this);

        menuComponentAbove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_above);
        menuComponentBelow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_below);
        menuComponentFront = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_front);
        menuComponentBack  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_component_back);
}
```

And remove that code from your init() method

Comment: What is the difference with this ??

Comment: This form was provided by google and I saw many examples that use this pattern ... And it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can you show where you use this custom FrameLayout ?